# Very fast cache / access time-indexed data in c#

Tags: c#, caching, performance

I'm coding a data intensive app in c#. Currently, the app loads loads and loads of timeseries from a distant sql server, does a lot of calculation to create other timeseries, and I'd like to access to these timeseries fast.

Each timeserie has a unique identifier, and should map from DateTime to anything (mostly floats, but sometime strings, stringarray, etc).

Do you know any library I could use for that, giving me :

- fast and parallel access to these timeseries ?
- access to the "tree" version of these timeseries, to lookup the latest date, last previous date, etc ?

I've had a look a massive parallel cache, such as memcached, tokyo-tyrant or redis, but I'd have to store a somehow serialized version of each timeseries to solve my problem.

Cheers !

Comment: Could you give us an example?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I misunderstood something crucial, but wouldn't the obvious solution be a `Dictionary<DateTime, object>()`?

E: If in-memory storage is out of the question, ignore this of course. A local database to store the information seems the most viable alternative if you are memory restricted.

Answer (score 0):

If you used a Document Database (e.g. [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/)) or Key-Value store you'd be able to do this.